# How to convert an email message from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8 string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, utf-8, pop3

I am getting data from a pop3 server and am unable to translate the text from ISO-8859-1 to utf-8. The text is below:

```
"To: "=?ISO-8859-1?B?Y24=?=" <cn@example.com>"
?ISO-8859-1?B?RndkOiBSZTogVVNDQQ==?=
```

Tried a few utf8 libraries but it didn't work.

Anyone know how to approach this problem?

Is it supposed to just translate the data in receiving email?

Can anyone point a direction? Many thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word

Comment: oh wow! thanks alot.